# Guzzle's cookie jar is only returning cookies from example.com and not www.example.com. Site is sending both

Tags: php, cookies, guzzle

I am using GuzzleHttp\Client in my Laravel app. I need to grab cookies from a list of domains (along with the source.) Grabbing everything else works great. Getting the cookies works, sort of.

The websites are returning cookies from only the base domain. So if I do the request to https://www.example.com. I am getting cookies for example.com. I am not getting the www.example.com cookies. And a surprising number of sites send both. When I check the sites out in Chrome, I see both sets of cookies.

How do I retrieve the cookies for the domain and all of its subdomains?

Here is the part of the code that gets the cookies:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar(false);

$res = $client->request('GET', $website, ['http_errors' => false, 'cookies' => $jar]);
$body = mb_convert_encoding($res->getBody()->getContents(), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
$cookies = '';
$it = $jar->getIterator();
while ($it->valid()) {
    $cookies .= $it->current() . "\r\n";
    $it->next();
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `mb_convert_encoding($res->getBody()->getContents(), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');`?

Comment: A few of the sites I was running through it were throwing errors on other calls later in the code. forcing it into UTF-8 solved my problems.

Comment: Yeah, but how is it forcing it into UTF-8? I have never seen such use of this function before.

Comment: You're going to have to inspect the requests in your browser to see exactly which call is getting the cookies, its obviously not the root document if guzzle isn't getting it.

Comment: @Scuzzy that is probably it. I hadn't thought about that in this example. I knew the various other cookies like facebook and google were all being caused by script calls and whatnot, but I didn't see that here because its all from the "same" domain, just the www version is sending the cookie I care about, but both are coming through.